# Proving that an operator converges in norm to the identity and that it is locally invertible.

Tags: operator-theory

[image]

Hello. I am looking at some results from the book one-parameter semigroups for linear evolution equations by authors engel and nagel. My questions are:

**Question 1**. Why does $1/tV(t)$ converge in norm to the identity operator?

**Question 2**. Why does the above imply that the operator $V(t)$ is invertible for $t$ sufficiently small?

My attempt for question 1 is as follows:

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{t}V(t)-Id&=\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}T(s)\,ds-\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}T(0)\,ds\\
&=\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}(T(s)-T(0))\,ds
\end{align}
But, I don't know if this last expression converges to $0$

**Actualization.**

I have already tried question 1. Question 2 not yet.

\begin{align}
\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}T(s)\,ds=\dot{V}(0)
\end{align} implies that $\lim_{t\to 0}\left\|\frac{1}{t}V(t)-Id\right\|_{X}=0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\e{\varepsilon}$ Fix $\e>0$. By definition of uniformly continuous, there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\|T(t)-I)\|<\e$ for all $t\in[0,\delta)$.  Then
\begin{align}
\|\tfrac1t\,V(t)-I\|
&\leq\tfrac1t\,\int_0^t\|T(t)-I\|\,dt\leq\tfrac1t\,t\e=\e. 
\end{align}

For your second question, it is standard that if $\|A-I\|<1$, then $A$ is invertible.  This is simply the fact that in such situation
$$
A^{-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (I-A)^k.
$$
The series  (often called the *Neumann series*) converges precisely because of the condition $\|I-A\|<1$.